# Relación de muchos a muchos, alumno perteneciente a un curso se inscribe en todos los cursos

Tags: php, base-de-datos, aplicación-web, grocery-crud

**Buenas, pues tengo un problema haciendo la relación de muchos a muchos y es que no entiendo por qué cuando inserto un alumno en un curso en concreto, el mismo aparece en todos los cursos. ¿Alguna solución al respecto?**

**BD**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi función del controlador donde hago la relación**

```
public function cursos_lista() {

    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    //$crud->unset_bootstrap();
    //---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/header.php'  ------------- /
    $datos = array(
        'title' => "cursos", // En la vista 'header' tendré una variable $title
        'username' => "Administrador"
    );

    $this->load->view('commons/header', $datos);

    $crud->set_language("spanish");
    $crud->set_theme('bootstrap');
    $crud->set_table('curso');

    $crud->columns('nombreCurso');

    //RELACION N_N THIS TABLE = CURSO / SELECTION TABLE = ALUMNO / RELATION TABLE = CURSO_ESCOLAR
    $crud->set_relation_n_n('alumnos', 'curso_escolar', 'alumno', 'Curso_idCurso', 'Alumno_idAlumno', 'nombreAlumno','anio');

    $crud->callback_column('nombreCurso', array($this, '_callback_nombre_curso'));

    $output = $crud->render();        


    $this->_example_output($output);


    //---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/footer.php'  ------------- /
    $this->load->view('commons/footer');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verificaste la pertenencia entre idAlumno & idCurso en Curso_escolar?

Siendo `Curso_escolar.Alumno_idAlumno = Alumno.idAlumno AND Curso_escolar.Curso_idCurso = Curso.idCurso`